# Is it possible to change the language of android phone by android code

Tags: android

I am try to change the language of android phone problematically using a code
but it give me a two exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException and java.lang.NullPointerException. Help me any body know how to resolve these exception.

```
public void changeLanguageSettings(Context con, Locale language) {
    try {
        //Linguagem definida
        Locale locale = language;

        Class amnClass = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManagerNative");
        Object amn = null;
        Configuration config = null;

        // amn = ActivityManagerNative.getDefault();
        Method methodGetDefault = amnClass.getMethod("getDefault");
        methodGetDefault.setAccessible(true);
        amn = methodGetDefault.invoke(amnClass);

        // config = amn.getConfiguration();
        Method methodGetConfiguration = amnClass
                .getMethod("getConfiguration");
        methodGetConfiguration.setAccessible(true);
        config = (Configuration) methodGetConfiguration.invoke(amn);

        // config.userSetLocale = true;
        Class configClass = config.getClass();
        Field f = configClass.getField("userSetLocale");
        f.setBoolean(config, true);

        // alterando a linguagem
        config.locale = locale;

        // amn.updateConfiguration(config);
        Method methodUpdateConfiguration = amnClass.getMethod(
                "updateConfiguration", Configuration.class);
        methodUpdateConfiguration.setAccessible(true);
        methodUpdateConfiguration.invoke(amn, config);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("error-->", "" + e.getMessage().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You kinda make it really hard if you want to change the user's default local you can do it like this:

```
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    // Change locale settings in the app.
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale(language);
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple:

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale(lang);
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

Where `lang` is obviously a language code like 'en', 'fr' or 'es'.